# Executing 'GRANT SELECT' in a trigger possible?

Tags: oracle, permissions, trigger

Trying to grant select privilege on table USER1.AAA to USER2 when table USER1.AAA is created, using system trigger.
The trigger below seems to be processed when table AAA is created but it receives errors ORA-00604, ORA-30511.

```
create or replace trigger aaa_trg
after create on schema 
begin
    if sys.dictionary_obj_name = 'AAA' then
        execute immediate 'GRANT SELECT ON AAA TO USER2';
    end if;
end;
/
```

It works fine when I execute 'INSERT' to AAA.
Is it possible to execute 'GRANT SELECT - ' like this ?

- DB is Oracle 12c R2.

Thanks.

Comment: On whose AAA table? What if there are 10 users in your database, each of them owning the AAA table?

Besides, in my opinion, such a thing shouldn't be done via triggers, but as a part of *create user* script.

Comment: No that's not possible. A DDL statement automatically commits the current transaction and you can't commit inside a trigger

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, are you sure? This is a database trigger, not a DML trigger. Apart from that, I don't think a `GRANT ...` commits the current transaction (but I am not sure)

Comment: What is the purpose of such a trigger. I assume table `AAA` is created (and dropped) on the fly inside a procedure. Maybe a GLOBAL TEMPORARY table or a MATERIALIZED VIEW would be the better approach. Or create a view `AAA`. When the underlying table is dropped and re-created then privileges on the View should persist.